# Why does xts shift a date one day back when creating an xts object from a data frame when TZ is not specified?

Tags: r, xts

Let me start by saying that I took a look at `?xts`, realised that this is a timezone related problem and seem to have resolved it, but I don't understand *why* it was happening. So: I have a simple data frame of price data. When I convert it to an `xts` object the first date of the `xts` object is a day earlier than the first date in the data frame. If I specify the time zone the dates match problem disappears. I thought at first it might be because `xts()` assumes that an `order.by` date without TZ specified is UMT, and `Sys.timezone()` gives "JST" for me but I don't see why that would lead to a date that is a full day earlier...?

**Q. Why is this happening?**

```
require(xts)
aa <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(6822, 6823, 6824, 6825, 6826,
6829), class = "Date"), Open = c(2145, 2126, 2130, 2148, 2144,
2137), High = c(2148, 2131, 2141, 2152, 2146, 2151), Low = c(2124,
2111, 2128, 2140, 2135, 2136), Close = c(2124, 2120, 2141, 2140,
2140, 2149), Volume = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("Date",
"Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume"), row.names = c(NA,
6L), class = "data.frame")

str(aa)
aa

bb <- xts(aa[5], order.by = aa$Date)
str(bb)
bb ## first date is a day earlier than the first day of the data frame

bb <- xts(aa[5], order.by = aa$Date, tzone = Sys.getenv("TZ"))
str(bb)
bb ## first dates in xts object and data frame match...
```

This is on:

```
sessionInfo():
R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22)

Platform: i386-pc-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[8] base     

other attached packages:
 [1] gridExtra_0.9.1 scales_0.2.2    plyr_1.7.1      ggplot2_0.9.2.1
 [5] lubridate_1.2.0 quantmod_0.3-17 TTR_0.21-1      xts_0.8-8      
 [9] zoo_1.7-9       Defaults_1.1-1 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] colorspace_1.2-0   dichromat_1.2-4    digest_0.5.2       gtable_0.1.1      
 [5] labeling_0.1       lattice_0.20-10    MASS_7.3-22        memoise_0.1       
 [9] munsell_0.4        proto_0.3-9.2      RColorBrewer_1.0-5 reshape2_1.2.1    
[13] stringr_0.6.1
```

> 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know, and I cannot exactly reproduce your problem, but I believe it has to do with the `Date`s being coerced to `POSIXct` and back.

This line is in the code for the `xts` function:

```
if (inherits(order.by, "Date") && !missing(tzone)) 
    order.by <- .POSIXct(unclass(order.by) * 86400, tz = tzone)
```

In your first call, `tzone` is missing, so this code is not executed.  In your
second call, `tzone` is not `missing`, so it is executed.

If you step through the code in xts.R, you can see that (if `tzone` is
`missing`) the `Dates` in `aa$Date` are coerced to `POSIXct`.

```
index <- as.numeric(as.POSIXct(order.by))
```

---

I think the issue is that `as.Date.POSIXct` has a default of `tz="UTC"`, so that is used unless you specify a different one.

```
x <- structure(1290125760, 
               tzone = structure("America/Chicago", .Names = "TZ"), 
               tclass = c("POSIXt", "POSIXct"), 
               class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))
x
#[1] "2010-11-18 18:16:00 CST"
str(x)
#POSIXct[1:1], format: "2010-11-18 18:16:00"
as.Date(x)
#[1] "2010-11-19"
as.Date(x, origin=as.Date("1970-01-01"), tz="America/Chicago")
#[1] "2010-11-18"
```

Comment: Interesting, thank you for that elucidation! Seems plausible enough to me and close to what I had suspected.

Comment: I am seeing this issue as well.  Seems to have popped out of nowhere.  Have been using XTS for past few months and everything has been fine - gone back to run some old code and am getting errors caused by this issue.

Comment: @mchangun, Jeff has just made a [commit](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php?view=rev&root=xts&revision=744) related to this.  Presumably, if you build/install the R-Forge version this problem should go away, but I couldn't replicate it to begin with...

Comment: This is related to an effort to remove edge case surprises related to mixing Date objects and POSIXct objects within xts objects. This will still cause problems as Date => 160 billion+ possible POSIXct microseconds when you account for TZs, but using Date in environments with varying TZ settings will no longer be an issue - Date indexing will always be derived from GMT POSIXct time on that day, or vice versa.  Hard to explain with only 500 characters in a comment, but that should provide some context.  An improved patch is in the works.