# Strange behaviour while accessing elements in an XTS

Tags: r, xts

I have an XTS that is part of a list `returns$sig` and from that XTS, I pull out a set of elements based on some conditions and store the Index in a variable `tstart`.

```
> tstart <- index(returns$sig[which(returns$sig != lag(returns$sig,1) & returns$sig != 0)])
> length(tstart)
[1] 599
```

When I try and access the `returns$sig` XTS again with the dates in `tstart`, I get a XTS with a different length:

```
> length(returns$sig[tstart])
[1] 478
```

It should return something with length 599.  If I try and access the XTS in a different way, I do get something of the same length:

```
> length(returns$sig[match(tstart,index(returns$sig))])
[1] 599
```

Spent hours on this and haven't found a resolution.  Is there something obvious that I am doing wrong? And to make matters worse, I swear that `length(returns$sig[tstart])` returned 599 yesterday and everything was working fine.

Comment: If something was "working fine" yesterday, did you try closing your R session and re-running your commands? Otherwise, please do try to share some code that reproduces your problem.

Comment: @mrdwab Sorry for the poorly formed question.  I couldn't reproduce the error with a short example and didn't want to post all my code.  I have finally figured out the issue.  It seems to be related to a [bug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341104/why-does-xts-shift-a-date-one-day-back-when-creating-an-xts-object-from-a-data-f/13441865#comment18593616_13441865) some ppl have been reporting with XTS.  All I needed to do was to specify a timezone for my system with `Sys.setenv(TZ = "GMT")`

Comment: @mchangun: can you post that as an answer to your question?  It would also be helpful if you specify which version of xts you're using.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Done.  I am using xts_0.8-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the poorly formed question. I couldn't reproduce the error with a short example and didn't want to post all my code. I have finally figured out the issue. It seems to be related to a [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341104/why-does-xts-shift-a-date-one-day-back-when-creating-an-xts-object-from-a-data-f/13441865#comment18593616_13441865) some ppl (myself included) have been reporting with XTS. All I needed to do was to specify a timezone for my system with Sys.setenv(TZ = "GMT").

For those that are interested, I am using `xts_0.8-8`.

Comment: Do you still experience the problem with the R-Forge version (without having to set the TZ environment variable)?

Comment: The R-Forge version is "Current" so you should be able to install it with `install.packages("xts", repos="http://r-forge.r-project.org")`.  If that doesn't work for some reason, see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11105131/cannot-install-r-forge-package-using-install-packages) about building from source.

Comment: @GSee Thanks - before I try that, how do I revert to the current CRAN version of XTS?  In case the R-Forge version has something in it that messes other stuff up.  Thanks.

Comment: Just install the CRAN version with `install.packages("xts")`, then that version will be used.

Comment: You can always use dput() on a subset of your _actual_ data and then modify with random data to protect the innocent.  The central issue is indeed TZ.  This will be fixed, but may not be yet - and key to fixing is reproducible reports.  Dates as POSIXct in R translate from 1 "Date" to over 160 BILLION possible microseconds within that 'day' when you account for TZ settings.  You can see the possible issues.

Comment: @GSee FYI, I still have the same problem with the R-Forge version of XTS.