# QUANTMOD package getSymbols (yahoo and alpha vantage) returns data for weekends

Tags: r, quantmod, alpha-vantage

I have a similar issue to [getSymbols (quantmod) giving wrong dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13998925/getsymbols-quantmod-giving-wrong-dates)  that does not solve by adding a TZ. My settings are:

```
R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Australia.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Australia.1252    
LC_MONETARY=English_Australia.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                       
LC_TIME=English_Australia.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] quantmod_0.4-13 TTR_0.23-2      xts_0.10-1      zoo_1.8-0
```

My timezone:

```
Sys.timezone()
> [1] "Australia/Sydney"

> Data <- getSymbols('BHP.AX',src="yahoo",auto.assign=FALSE, from = '2017-
10-10')
> weekdays(head(index(Data),20))
 [1] "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Sunday"    "Monday"    
"Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Sunday"    "Monday"    "Tuesday"   
"Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Sunday"   
[16] "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Sunday"
```

As you can see, the data returns Sundays. I've also seen similar returns using the Alpha Vantage option - Fridays are regularly omitted in the tail of the returned data. Any tips to avoid this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of the cause, and without carefully inspecting the source I'd be speculating. And I would guess that because Monday in Australia (where the stock is traded, `.AX`) typically corresponds to Sunday in North America, plus or minus a few hours depending on the time zone, the data is recorded using the North American date.

I also get that the Sun to Thurs dates are returned even if I set my timezone to US EST before making the data call.

```
Sys.timezone()
#[1] "America/New_York"



unique(weekdays(index(Data)))
# [1] "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Sunday"
```

But here is a solution to your problem:

```
library(lubridate)
index(Data) <- index(Data) + days(1)

unique(weekdays(index(Data)))
# [1] "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Friday"    "Monday"
```

Or without using `lubridate`, if you are sure your time index is type "Date" and not "POSIXct", this also works (adding plus 1 increments the date):

```
index(Data) <- index(Data) + 1
```

The above shows that no Saturday or Sunday dates are returned, as expected (the stock doesn't trade weekends).

Adding one day gives sensible results.  Look at the most recent dates after adjustment:

```
tail(Data)
           BHP.AX.Open BHP.AX.High BHP.AX.Low BHP.AX.Close BHP.AX.Volume BHP.AX.Adjusted
2017-12-29       29.65      29.760      29.51        29.57       4428226           29.57
2018-01-02       29.57      29.750      29.50        29.68       3252955           29.68
2018-01-03       30.24      30.350      30.17        30.18       6788783           30.18
2018-01-04       30.42      30.605      30.30        30.33       5501131           30.33
2018-01-05       30.65      30.690      30.51        30.58       5835685           30.58
2018-01-08       30.55      30.660      30.44        30.55       3274512           30.55
> unique(weekdays(index(Data)))
```

2017-12-29 was a Friday.  2018-01-01 was a public holiday, and 2018-01-02 was a Tuesday.

Comment: Hi FXQ - thank you so much for the quick response.  I think you've pointed me in the right direction, I agree it looks like the 'record time' is in another timezone, and as I don't know how to wrangle a time out of quantmod, I'm not sure how exactly to revert the reading to Oz time. I have a work around which I'll put below. Don't laugh! but it is very similiar to your answer, and seems to work across all dates of the year.

Answer (score 0):

Ok - Thanks to FXQ to pointing out the tz issue, and for the speedy answer. I've had a think and a go at resolving the dates to oz time, using this ugly workaround. First, moved the XTS into a data.table and then:

```
 #### re-allign to AUS dates  
    happyDays <- function(x) {
    # find range of dates
    mini        <- min(x$index)
    maxi        <- max(x$index)+3
    aus         <- paste(seq.Date(mini, maxi,1), "14:55")    #13:40
    pb.date1    <- as.POSIXct(aus, tz="Australia/Sydney")
    AUS_index   <- pb.date1#[!weekdays(pb.date1) %in% c("Saturday","Sunday")]
    tradeDaysUS <- format(AUS_index, tz="America/Chicago",usetz=TRUE)
    US_date     <- as.Date(tradeDaysUS)

    dt          <- data.table(AUS_index, US_date= as.Date(US_date))
    #dt[,.N,by=US_date][N>1]

    x$original_index <- x$index
    x <- merge(x, dt, by.x="index", by.y="US_date", all.x=TRUE)
    x$AUS_date <- as.Date(x$AUS_index)
    x$index <- x$AUS_date
    x[,weekdays:=weekdays(AUS_index)]
    x
  }

  hilo <- happyDays(hilo)
```

I can't help but think I've over-complicated this - there must be an easier way to take the output of getSymbols in a mon - fri week. I guessed the timezone and times - and checked the output against the original yahoo data. very.ugly.